# Как принудительно завершить работу AsyncTaskLoader

Tags: android, loader

Допустим, в методе `loadInBackground` `AsyncTaskLoader'a` я пытаюсь загрузить данные из сети. В случае, если данные не загрузились, мне нужно принудительно завершить работу метода `loadInBackground`. Каким методом можно это осуществить?

Comment: В заголовке вы хотите завершить loader. В описании: вызвать принудительную загрузку. Уточните, пожалуйста.

Comment: @DanielShatz, спасибо, исправил :)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Если хотите прерывать работу из вне(например, по нажатию кнопки):***

Добавьте глобальную переменную `boolean cancelled = false;`.

В `onClick` присвойте `true` к `cancelled`.

Затем, в методе `loadInBackground`, в месте, где логично прерывать работу, сделайте `if(cancelled) return;`

Если хотите прервать работу, когда не удалось что-то загрузить, то в нужный момент сделайте `return`.

В общем, работа `AsyncTaskLoader` заканчивается при завершении выполнения метода `loadInBackground`.

Comment: Хм... А я об этом даже не подумал... Спасибо :).